# Same Title Bar but different View below it in Android?

Tags: android, button, android-activity

In one of my Android Application I need to keep the title bar same but the view that is shown in the rest of the screen changes. So, I have taken different Activity for all the views that I need to show and set the title bar in every Activities onCreate method.

Now, the problem is that I have a button in the title bar and need to perform certain action on its click event. Writing the same event handling code in every Activity class is very cumbersome. Is there any other way out that whenever there is a click event on that button of the title bar then we can have the same functionality without writing the same code in all the Activity classes.

Can we use ViewGroup for that? I don't have much idea about ViewGroup. Is that possible with ViewGroup?

If anyone knows the solution then please let me know.

Thanks & Regards
Sunil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sharing view elements and functionality amongst several classes extending `Activity`, you might want to consider making a common superclass to handle this overlap.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is to keep a base activity like this.

```
        public class HeaderBaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
        @Override
            public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
                getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

                mAppPreferences = AppUtil.getAppPreferences(this);
                item_patients =  menu.findItem(R.id.item_patients);
                setBatchCountOnMenu(0);

                RealmConfiguration realmConfig = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(this).build();
                mRealm = Realm.getInstance(realmConfig);
                mDotor = new Gson().fromJson(mAppPreferences.getString(Constants.SETTINGS_OBJ_DOCTOR, ""), Doctor.class);
                mAppPreferences = AppUtil.getAppPreferences(this);
                return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

            }

            @Override
            public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.action_logout:
                       /* DialogUtility.showShortToast(this, " Main manu Action Logout");*/
                        SharedPreferences.Editor Editor = mAppPreferences.edit();
                        Editor.putBoolean(Constants.SETTINGS_IS_LOGGED_IN, false);
                        Editor.apply();
                        clearRealmDB();
                        Intent loginIntent = new Intent(HeaderBaseActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                        loginIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
                        startActivity(loginIntent);
                        finish();
                        break;
                    case R.id.item_patients:
                        System.out.println("current activity "+getApplicationContext());
                        Intent mPatientListIntent = new Intent(HeaderBaseActivity.this, PatientSummaryInfoActivity.class);
                        mPatientListIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        startActivity(mPatientListIntent);
                        break;

                    case R.id.action_doctor_profile:
                        openDialogOfDoctorProfile();
                        break;   
                }
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }


        }


    Your other activities can extend the above activity like this:

        public class MainActivity extends HeaderBaseActivity{
         protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                ButterKnife.bind(this);
         setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            }

        }
```